# Problem with spreading sequence in dsss

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with a DSSS communication. On reception, if I use another sequence for despreading, I have a BER equal to 0. However, this is impossible. Do you know where my mistake is?

This is my code:

```
clear all;close all;clc;

%% Data
Ba=20e3; %bandwidth
fe=100e3; %sampling frequency
R=fe/Ba;
SF=32; %spreading factor
srrc=rcosdesign(0.25,12,R,'sqrt');
nb_bit=2e2;
Nf=1e2; %number of frame
SNR=20;
N0=10^(-SNR/10);

for num_fra=1:Nf
    %% Spreading sequence
    pn=2*(rand(1,SF)>0.5)-1;
    pnup=upsample(pn,R);
    sweep=filter(srrc,1,pnup);
        
    pn2=2*(rand(1,SF)>0.5)-1; %other pn sequence
    pnup2=upsample(pn2,R);
    sweep2=filter(srrc,1,pnup2);
    
    %% Binary message
    m=double(rand(1,nb_bit)>0.5);
    
    %% Modulation
    u=zeros(size(m));
    u(:,1)=m(:,1);
    for k=2:size(m,2)
        u(:,k) = ~(mod(m(:,k)+u(:,k-1),2)); %differential modulation DBPSK
    end
    
    ak=2*u-1; 
    
    %% Spreading
    s=kron(ak,sweep);
    s=s/sqrt(mean(abs(s).^2));
    
    %% Gaussian channel
    n=sqrt(N0/2)*(randn(size(s))+1i*randn(size(s))); 
    r=s+n;
    
    %% Despreading
    dec=xcorr(r,sweep2); %other pn sequence
    dec=dec(size(r,2):size(sweep,2):end);
    
    %% Demodulation
    v1=zeros(size(dec));
    v1(:,1)=ak(1);
    v1(:,2:end)=conj(dec(:,2:end)).*dec(:,1:end-1);
    mhat=double(v1>0);
    
    %% BER
    BER(num_fra)=sum(mhat~=m)/nb_bit;
end
```

Comment: Where is the receiver code that is giving you a BER of 0? DBPSK is best avoided in preference of plain BPSK in DSSS systems.

Comment: It's not obvious to me upon quick inspection of your code what the issue is. I suggest that you single step through your code and review each result. When you get to the line that doesn't make sense to you, please provide what you are getting and what you would have expected. This will help provide more focus to your question.